# SSIS 2012 Passing Parameters / Passwords with Dont Save Sensitive

Tags: configuration, parameters, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have got a package and I want to pass username, password and server name via the **Project Parameters**.  I managed to set it, deployed to SSIS Server and it run successfully in the server.

[image: My Project Parameters]

However, as soon as I set the Protection Level to 'Dont Save Sensitive', I couldn't run the package in my development PC anymore.

[image: Package Configuration]

After changing that, the package cannot access to the Database anymore and **Project Parameters** are no longer tied to the package.

[image]

In SSIS 2008, we used Package Configuration XML files and by using that XML file, we can run in both Development and Live environment at the same time.

Is there anyway to achieve the same in SSIS 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Your package needs to have a Parameter for each of the Project Parameters you are trying to pass.

Then your Connection Managers need to use those Variables - usually as Expressions to form a ConnectionString property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Store the password in a config file (not the best idea but it does work)
2. Store the project parameter as sensitive. Then you've gotta use things like the GetSensitive method to decrypt that data.